# How does CLR compile Q# code that uses or does not make use of qubits?

Tags: clr, q#, qubit

If a Q# operation does not use qubits or quatum specific gates, will then the CLR generate bytecode that will be executed by the CPU and not the QPU(quantum processor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly. The Q# compiler translates the purely classical parts of your code into C#, which gets compiled (by the C# compiler) into standard .NET MSIL, JITed by the .NET Core runtime, and executed on a normal CPU.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For a while I thought that any code I write in Q# uses in the back-end the quantum processor. But this is sneaky, yet clear what it's doing. Thank you again!